# Period Homomorphisms and closed 1-forms

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, differential-forms, contour-integration

This is from Otto Forster's "lectures on Riemann Surfaces", on integration of forms.

Let $\Gamma = \alpha_1 \mathbb{Z} + \alpha_2 \mathbb{Z}$ be a lattice in $\mathbb{C}$ (i.e. $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{C}$ and are lin. independent over $\mathbb{R}$), and $X := \mathbb{C} / \Gamma$ a torus.   Given any homomorphism (of groups)
\begin{equation*}
a: \pi_1(X) \to \mathbb{C}
\end{equation*}
show that there exists a closed 1-form $\omega \in \mathcal{E}^1(X)$ (smooth 1-forms on $X$) whose period homomorphism is equal to $a$.

**My Attempt** (so far):

So first off, recall that the "period homomorphism" of a closed 1-form $\omega \in \mathcal{E}^1(X)$ is the map
\begin{equation*}
\gamma \mapsto \int_\gamma \omega  \quad \text{   $\gamma \in \pi_1(X)$}
\end{equation*}
(which is nice and well-defined, since the integral of a closed 1-form is invariant under homotopic deformations of $\gamma$).  Since $\pi_1(X) \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, the given map $a$ is uniquely determined by the images of the two fundamental cycles, which are the images of the two curves $\gamma_i: [0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $t \mapsto t\alpha_i$, under the canonical projection $p: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}/\Gamma$.

What I *want* to do is find some nice function $F : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ that is additively automorphic (w/ constant summands of automorphy) under $\text{Deck}(\mathbb{C}/ X)$ so that there exists a closed 1-form $\omega \in \mathcal{E}^1(X)$ such that $dF = p^*\omega$.  For then we have 
\begin{equation*}
\int_{p \circ \gamma_i} \omega = \int_{\gamma_i} dF = F(\alpha_i)-F(0)
\end{equation*}
and by (maybe) scaling $F$ in different ways, I can force the integral to be equal to $a(p \circ \gamma_i)$.

Or am I way off?  Anybody?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. Note that you can choose F to be real-linear by prescribing its values at $\alpha _{1}, \alpha _{2}$. Also, such functions have the needed behaviour under the group of deck transformations (which acts by translations).

Comment: I'm also attempting this exercise and I have defined an $F: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ by $F(z) = \frac{\beta_1 - \beta_2}{\alpha_1 - \alpha_2}(z - \alpha_2) + \beta_2$ where $\beta_i = a(p \circ \gamma_i)$. My problem is that $F(0)$ doesn't seem to vanish, so I was wondering if you could tell me if I was on the right track? Apologies for asking a question in a comment, but it didn't seem worth it to ask a completely new one.